# How many types of the restricts available in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Why is it when we create a directive, it is restricted to attribute only by default. In order to create directives that are triggered by element or class name, we need to use the restrict option?

The restrict option is typically set to:

- 'A' - only matches attribute name,
- 'E' - only matches element name,
- 'C' - only matches class name.

These restrictions can all be combined as needed:

- 'AEC' - matches either attribute or element or class name.

Only these restricts are available in angularjs? Or, are any other restricts are available?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

AngularJS by default is expecting that we will declare a custom directive as an attribute so it means that the `restrict` option is set to `A`.

Available options are:

`E` = **Element**
`<new-directive></new-directive>`

`A` = **Attribute** *(Default)*
`<div new-directive="expr"></div>`

`C` = **Class**
`<div class="new-directive: expr;"></div>`

`M` = **Comment**
`<!-- directive: new-directive expr -->`

They of course could be used in combination:

```
{ restrict: 'EC' } // Element or class
```

Attributes are the default for the because they will really work cross-browser, including older IEs without registration of new tags in the document.

I was advised and I advise as well not to use comment restriction to declare directives, because they were to span multiple elements, but in newer versions there are hooks like ng-repeat-end and so on.

Comment: Yes. I would recommend against using it though.

Comment: restrict properties you mean.

Comment: FYI: documentation for 'restrict' is within the $compile API now,          http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile

Comment: And this is where directive get compiled in the angular source: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/compile.js

Answer (score 0):

Extracted from [angular documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24compile#-restrict-):

`restrict`
String of subset of EACM which restricts the directive to a specific directive declaration style. If omitted, the default (attributes only) is used.

- `E` - Element name: `<my-directive></my-directive>`
- `A` - Attribute (default): `<div my-directive="exp"></div>`
- `C` - Class: `<div class="my-directive: exp;"></div>`
- `M` - Comment: `<!-- directive: my-directive exp -->`